# Debian 7 apt is upgrading my custom backported package with the "official" identical version!

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, backports

and happy new year to you all..

Recently I've built nginx deb package v1.4.4 from debian backport source that of course I've added to the apt sources.list and things went great.

I have run `apt-get update` then `apt-get -V upgrade` today to check how debian 7 apt would behave.. and this is what I got:

```
root@debian-lab:~/nginx-1.4.4-packages# apt-get -V upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
   nginx-full (1.4.4-1~bpo70+1 => 1.4.4-1~bpo70+1)
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/464 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,027 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

As you can see, apt is trying to upgrade from **(1.4.4-1~bpo70+1 => 1.4.4-1~bpo70+1)**, which is basically two identical version but my installed deb package has custom nginx modules added to default nginx-full and after the update, my custom modules are all gone and replaced by the standard debian wheezy backport deb.. I've built my nginx backport deb package from debian backport source and installed build-deb through the backport as well but some dependencies installed automatically from the stable that's what I saw from the verbose output..

Can you please help me to prevent this with an example? I heard about pinning, but is it the answer to my problem?

---

**UPDATE**

I've tried to apt pin the package and didn't work and here is the output i got:

```
apt-cache policy nginx-full
nginx-full:
Installed: 1.4.4-1~bpo70+1
Candidate: 1.4.4-1~bpo70+1
Version table:
 1.4.4-1~bpo70+1 0
    100 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports/main amd64 Packages
*** 1.4.4-1~bpo70+1 0
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 1.2.1-2.2+wheezy2 0
    500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

And the following is the apt-cache policy nginx:

```
/etc/apt/preferences.d# apt-cache policy nginx
nginx:
  Installed: 1.4.4-1~bpo70+1
  Candidate: 1.4.4-1~bpo70+1
  Package pin: 1.4.4-1~bpo70+1
  Version table:
 *** 1.4.4-1~bpo70+1 1001
        100 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.2.1-2.2+wheezy2 1001
        500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

But still apt is trying to upgrade and replace it!!

Sources.list content:

```
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main

# Wheezy Backports repository
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main
```

I've tried to apt pin once the package name 'nginx' and another time with nginx-full..

But both fail to hold the package!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12230/discussion-between-strugee-and-dr-sms)

Comment: if i changed the package version from changelog file, then what should i do in case the backport package has received a security update. does that mean I should build the package again from the new patched source manually?

Comment: You need to up the version. Consider dch -l. Yes, you'll have to rebuild with the new source package for security (etc.) updates. Use a VCS, that'll make it easier. (Sorry, on phone, can't write a real answer)

Comment: Please list the output of `apt-cache policy nginx-full`. This should not happen if backports are set to a low priority. I thought they were. I set the backports to 50 myself. Ok, checking the backports page, it says `All backports are deactivated by default (i.e. the packages are pinned to 100 by using ButAutomaticUpgrades: yes in the Release files.` I guess this is to make sure that if you are using backports, that they are automatically upgraded if a new version is available. One option is to up the version as others have suggested, the other is to pin at a lower priority.

Comment: Upping the version is a lot of hassle.. but I just wanna know why is pinning is not working!!

Comment: Please post your `/etc/apt/preferences` or wherever you put your apt pinning for the package.

Comment: You don't need to list policy for both `nginx` and `nginx-full`. `nginx` is just a dummy package for pulling in the real packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid problems, first, I would suggest you to **use a custom (and greater) version number for your custom package**, for example : `1.4.4-1~bpo70+1-mrsms`. This would only be fair because your package is not the same exact version as the "official" backport. You can change the version number from the file `debian/changelog` before you build it.

You can test version comparison with `dpkg` (here, `gt` stands for "greater than", the return code is `0` if the expression is true):

```
$ dpkg --compare-versions 1.4.4-1~bpo70+1-mrsms gt 1.4.4-1~bpo70+1
$ echo $?
```

Be careful because your custom package will still be upgraded if an even greater version is found on the online repository. I would then suggest you to **use [pinning](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man5/apt_preferences.5.html) to avoid that** (see `man apt_preferences`).

You may try this by creating a file, say `/etc/apt/preferences.d/nginx-full`, with this content:

```
Package: nginx-full
Pin: version 1.4.4-1~bpo70+1-mrsms
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

**You can also *hold* the package** in it's current installed state, that's very effectual, but not very elegant (might trouble future upgrades):

```
# aptitude hold nginx-full
# echo "nginx-full" hold |dpkg --set-selections
```

Comment: Thanks,, but someone suggested i use:  Package: nginx
Pin: version 1.4.4-1~bpo70+1
Pin-Priority: 1001 ,, but it's not working.. I don't use aptitude only apt-get.. I tried to build the package with fake high version like 1.7.7 which is very unlikely to be released anytime soon.. Does it really matter what number I put in `debian/changelog` version? is it in anyway dangerous? and then what about security updates in the future? BTW, I've build the nginx backport package with some build dependencies from backport repository by running apt-get -t wheezy-backports build-dep nginx..

Comment: It is worth noting that apt-pinning is buggy insofar as `apt-get` and `aptitude` don't necessarily respect each other's pins/holds. I forget the details; I just use `apt-get`. I second the recommendation for increasing the version number. This will of course mean that you don't get security upgrades automatically, but this is inevitable with a custom package; you can't have everything.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I agree about holds (that's why I use 2 different commands to hold). However, I didn't know about pinning. Is there an open bug report for this?

Comment: @Totor I think I may be mistaken about apt pinning. I think I was confusing it with holds.

Comment: @Dr.SMS If you're pinning on the version number, of course it didn't change anything since both packages shared the same. You should try pinning on "origin" or some other relevant criterion. Personally, I wouldn't have used a fake version number because it could be misleading. It is not "dangerous", but it might get slightly tricky if you want to go back to the official release one day or if you upgrade your distribution. As *FaheemMitha* pointed out, you loose the benefit of security update because *you* become the maintainer of your own package, hence you must recompile to stay secure... :)

Comment: @Totor I figured out that too late. I mean people here can be very misleading. It should have been obvious to them that both have same version. so it was like I did nothing.. Regarding security, my site is just a personal blog, and i guess nginx security holes are way complicated for an ordinary hacker to exploit. so i'll have enough time for that.. I accepted your answer as because at least you were the most helpful and concise but I urge you to at least put an example of pinning this particular package since your link is very useless at pointing that out. Looking forward to your edit. Thanks

Comment: @Dr.SMS I've edited my answer (and link). However, I "urge" you to read `man apt_preferences` to understand pinning.

Comment: @Totor I've already read it :) .. Unfortunately your first link was useless when it comes to pinning priorities numbering.. but it's great that you've changed the link.. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @Dr.SMS I'm not a big fan of your edit. Did you find that my version wasn't working? The fact is that if you ever set up a local repository with your package inside, pinning on `origin` and a 995 priority is better, because when you put a newer version of your package in that local repo., it will be automatically upgraded when you do `apt-get upgrade`. Your version is more straightforward to understand, but does not allow that.

Answer (score 3):

In chat, OP stated that he installed his package with `dpkg --install`. Additionally, IIRC, APT parses which package it prefers in the following way:

1. If a package is pinned, don't do anything with it.
2. Prefer whichever package known to the system has the highest program version.
3. If there are conflicts, prefer whichever package known to the system has the highest package version.
4. If there are still conflicts, prefer packages from a repository listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.
5. If there are still conflicts, prefer a package from whichever repository comes first in `sources.list`.

Armed with this information, we can posit that APT is choosing the repository version over the locally installed version at step 4. So, there are four ways to solve this problem:

1. Increase the package version to something beyond what the official Debian repositories provide. This will cause your locally installed package to be selected over the Debian package during step 3. (@Totor beat me to it, so I'll defer to his answer for instructions on how to do this.)
2. Increase the program version to something beyond what the official Debian repositories provide. This will get your package selected during step 2, but I would highly recommend not doing this and instead incrementing the package version - there's no technical reason, it's just more correct. However, if you do choose to do it this way, it is done in basically the same way as the package version, except that you change a different field in your [`debian/control` file](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html) (or whatever else you are using to generate your package).
3. Pin your package. This will cause your package to be selected during step 1. Again, this is covered in @Totor's answer.
4. Create a local repository, put your package in it, and ensure that when you add it to your `sources.list`, it comes before the official Debian repositories. This will trigger a selection in step 5. In order to do this, refer to [this Debian Wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository). You may also be interested in [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/q/170348), if you want an easier tutorial-style reference.

Comment: I guess you are wrong about the control file.. it has no version numbers or anything.. I'm just gonna try the `changelog` file since most of articles out there say that its first line is what determines the package release and version numbers and I guess they are right because I've tried it once and it worked. So I guess it's better to delete that part in your answer.. Ciao!

Comment: @Dr.SMS if you find that works instead of `debian/control`, please feel free to edit my answer. like I said, I'm not an expert in Debian packaging by a long shot.